# Given N arrays, how many ways are there for each array to contribute one element and add to k?

Tags: algorithm

Say I had N arrays. These N arrays are in an array of arrays A. How many N-tuples are there such that for a tuple t,

```
sum = 0
for i = 0 ... N-1
    sum += A[i][t[i]]
sum == k
```

What is an efficient way to solve this? The best I can come up with is just enumerating all possibilities.

P.S. This isn't a homework question. I saw [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum-ii/) on LeetCode and was curious about a solution to the general case.

Comment: This is a variation of the subset sum problem and NP-complete.

Comment: @NicoSchertler can you explain how?

Comment: How the problem can be solved? Just google for it and you get some algorithms (e.g. the Wikipedia article has a few).

Comment: @NicoSchertler I can see the similarity between this and the subset sum problem. I was just wondering you if you can show how this problem can be reduced to subset sum?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I highly doubt it is NP complete. The naive approach of considering each touple will be `O(num_elems^num_arrays)` - for any given `num_arrays`, is P-complete.

Comment: Granted, your problem is a bit easier than subset sum because you know the number of elements and where they should be. You still have an exponential search space, which makes me believe that it is still NP-complete.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi How is O(k^N) polynomial (in both N and k)?

Comment: @NicoSchertler - I said "**for any given `num_arrays`** the naive solution is polynomial".

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi That is like saying *for any given array length, sorting the array takes constant time*. You can't just cut important variables out of your analysis, especially when the OP already introduced them as part of the problem.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Ok, sure, I retract the justification why I think is not an NP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptual solution (can be improved):

1. sort the elements in each array
2. shift the elements in each array by the absolute minimum of all arrays (`abs_min` - to shift all arrays you'll subtract the `abs_min` from each element of all arrays) - you now have all arrays with non-negative elements and you are searching for a `target_sum = initial_sum - num_arrays*abs_min`
3. set your `curr_array` as the first one
4. binary search for the position of `target_sum` in the `curr_array`. You will need to consider all the elements in `curr_array` with indices under this position. Take one such element, subtract it from the `target_sum`, and recursively repeat the search with the next array.

I believe the (amortised) complexity will be somewhere of `O(num_arrays*N*log(N))` where `N` is the (maximum) number of elements in the arrays.

Opportunities for improvement:

1. I kinda feel that shifting all arrays by `abs_min` is unnecessary (just an artifice that helps the thinking). Maybe before going one step deeper in recursion in step 4, the `target_sum` may be shifted by the min of current array?
2. reordering the arrays so that the shorter ones are considered first will *perhaps* improve the performance (lower number of elements in the upper levels of the recursion to consider) **[Edit]** or maybe reordering the arrays in the descending order of their min value (take out from the `target_sum` in the most aggressive way possible)?
3. adopting a scheme which eliminate/multiplexes the duplicates inside the initial arrays may help - i.e a map with the index_key=unique_value and the map-value the set of indexes). If the specific tuples are not required, then a map of unique-value->occurrence_count would be enough. (this may be useful if one can be sure that duplicate exist - e.g. the values in the arrays are within tight ranges and arrays are pretty long - pigeonhole principle)

---

[Edited to show how it works in the example of `{{1, 2, 3}, {42,43, 44, 45, 46, 47}}`]

Upper limit = index of the element **strictly greater** than the provided value. If you want values lesser or equal, take values **strictly below** that index!!

Zero-based index convention

1. `49` target sum in the first array gets the upper limit of `index=3` (so all indexes under 3 need to to be considered)
2. first array - start index=`2` / value=`3` in the first array, you will be looking for a `target_sum` of `46` in the second. Upper limit by binary search in the second is `index=5` (and will be looking strictly under), so start with `index=4`/value=`46` (the algo cuts out the value of `47`). `46` is good and retained, `index=3`/`value=45` is not enough and (not having a 3-rd array to recurse into it) the algo won't even consider under `index=3`/`value=45`.
3. first array, `index=1`/`value=2`, looking for a target_sum of `47` in the second array. Get an upper limit (binary search) affords `index=7` (to search strictly under it) so `index=6`/`value=47`. `47` is retained, `46` and below and the algo cut out
4. down in the first array, `index=0`/`value=1`, looking for a target_sum of `48` in the second array. Upper limit is again `7`, at `index=6`/`value=47` we get an insufficient value and terminate.

So, grand totals:

- Total binary searches: 1-in the first array, 3 in the second.
- Total successful equalities tested=2 (two tuples found).
- Total unsuccesful equalities tested=3 (until the second array does no longer offer a satisfactory answer).
- Total additions/subtraction performed=3 (one for each value in the first array)

By contrast, the exhaustive scanning would get:

- no binary searches
- total additions = 3*6=18
- total successful equality tested = 2
- total un-successful equality tested = 16

Comment: This is still exponential in the number of arrays because you have to consider every combination.

Comment: @NicoSchertler "This is still exponential in the number of arrays because you have to consider every combination. " Nope. I'm binary searching in sorted arrays for the sum at each recursion step. If at any recursion step I don't find a solution the recursion is terminated. E.g it will be terminated immediately when the target sum is under min or over max of the current_array. Suppose that you have a single array - how many steps to find your sum if the array is sorted?

Comment: But you don't know the sum for a specific array. You only know the sum of all arrays. And this does not necessarily distribute evenly. Consider the arrays `{{1, 2, 3}, {45, 46, 47}}` and you search for sum `49`. According to your logic, you would break the recursion at the first array, but this would be wrong.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I said 'binary search for the index' (should have said for the `upper_limit` in C++ parlance) and 'need to consider all the elements below that limit.`

Comment: And what is `upper_limit`? If you mean the sum, then you will still consider all elements of both arrays.

Comment: @NicoSchertler "And what is upper_limit?" It's the index of the first element with a value greater than sum. Will edit the answer to show how it works on your example (the comments are too short)

Comment: @NicoSchertler - example provided, I increased the size of the second array to make the impact more visible.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this approach can reduce the number of candidates. However, it is just a heuristic and will only jump in for the last arrays (when the sum is already high). It will still have exponential run time. By the way, all these preprocessing steps (shift, sort, binary search) are superfluous. Just iterate the values and check if they are good. Going from the highest number down is another heuristic, which actually needs the sort to be efficient. But I am not convinced of this heuristic as a fast decrease will usually not result in a correct sum.

Comment: @NicoSchertler "it is just a heuristic and will only jump in for the last arrays (when the sum is already high". With minor tweaking, it will jump on the middles too (tweaking: keep a bottom-up array with the max sum that the arrays below can offer. If the target_sum goes under what the below can compensate, you jump out of the recursion earlier). "(shift, sort, binary search) are superfluous" Shit yes, sort and binary search, no. Look, I agree that **the worst case complexity** will be exponential, however, in the average case, one can expect a much lower amortized complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Language: C++
Constraints: A[i][j] >= 0
Complexity: O(N * k)

```
int A [MAX_N][MAX_N], memo[MAX_N][MAX_K+1];

int countWays2(int m, int sum, int N){
    if(memo [m][sum] != -1)
        return memo [m][sum];

    if(m == 0)
        return memo[m][sum] =  count(A[0], A[0]+N, sum);

    int ways = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if(sum >= A[m][i])
            ways += countWays2(m-1, sum - A[m][i], N);

    return memo[m][sum] = ways;
}

int countWays(int N, int k){
    if(k < 0) return 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        fill(memo[i], memo[i] + k + 1, -1);     //Initialize memoization table

    return countWays2(N-1, k, N);
}
```

The answer is countWays(N, k)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You should explain what the code does. At least, define what `k` is.

Comment: `int A [MAX_N][MAX_N]` Mmm, assuming the code is correct, for 10^5 elements in the arrays, the extra space complexity drives the problem in the 38GB range (32bit ints).